# Error loading mysql2 when trying to run ruby app on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm trying to run a ruby app i cloned from github on mylocalhost and get the following error when entering 'rails s' in the command:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from C:/Users/uklar/Documents/GitHub/Budget-Requests-New/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

C:\Users\uklar\Documents\GitHub\Budget-Requests-New [master +0 ~2 -0]>

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update:** After downloading the libmysql.dll file and putting it in my ruby directory i get these messages:

```
    => Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant JSON
Exiting
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (Mysql2::Error)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__435324379__prepare__609126447__callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from c:/users/uklar/documents/github/budget-requests-new/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/users/uklar/documents/github/budget-requests-new/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from c:/users/uklar/documents/github/budget-requests-new/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from c:/users/uklar/documents/github/budget-requests-new/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you: 1. install the mysql gem, 2. have mysql installed? You don't provide a lot of details.

Comment: sorry about that... i'm preety new to this so i'm not sure what details to provide :) the answer to both of your question is yes

Comment: what does your database.yml look like?

Comment: you need to install mysql database server, and start it

Comment: thanks. starting the server was the solution. also, i had to rum the comand prompt as administrator. thanks

Comment: ROR with windows as the paths shows :( !!  i would suggest to go for unix based os

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so solution was:

1. Download libmysql.dll file and put it in ruby directory
2. open command prompt as administratoe and start the mysql server the following way:
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld